# Synchronised Threads Mixed Up

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

Output:

```
Produced food '20'
Produced food '19'
Eaten food '20'
Eaten food '19'
Eaten food '18'
Produced food '18'
Produced food '17'
Eaten food '17'
Produced food '16'
Eaten food '16'
Produced food '15'
Eaten food '15'
Produced food '14'
Eaten food '14'
Produced food '13'
Eaten food '13'
Produced food '12'
Eaten food '12'
Eaten food '11'
Produced food '11'
Produced food '10'
Eaten food '10'
Produced food '9'
Eaten food '9'
Produced food '8'
Eaten food '8'
Produced food '7'
Eaten food '7'
Produced food '6'
Eaten food '6'
Eaten food '5'
Produced food '5'
Produced food '4'
Eaten food '4'
Produced food '3'
Eaten food '3'
Produced food '2'
Eaten food '2'
Produced food '1'
Eaten food '1'
Produced food '0'
Eaten food '0'
```

I want ONE food to produce THEN one food to consume in sequence

Code:

```
int times =0;
// read `times` using input

while(times < 20 || times > 100) {
    if (times < 3000) {
        System.out.println("No less than 3000! I am hungry");
        times = (int) cin("----->How much i should eat? in numbers?");
    }
    if(times > 20000){
        System.out.println("I cant eat that much!");
        times = (int) cin("----->How much i should eat? in numbers?");
    }
}
food me = new food();
me.eat(times);
```

Class Code:

```
class food{

    public int times;
    public int food;
    public boolean canget=false;

    void eat(int times){

        this.times = times;
        producer p = new producer();
        p.produce(this);
        consumer pe = new consumer();
        pe.consume(this);


    }

    synchronized void add(int n){
        while(canget) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something nasty happened");
            }
        }

        this.food = n;
        canget = true;
        notify();
    }
    synchronized int get(){
        while (!canget){
            try{
                wait();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something Nasty happened");
            }
        }
        canget = false;
        notify();
        return this.food;
    }
}
```

---

```
class producer implements Runnable{
    int times;
    food f;

    void produce(food F){
        times=F.times;
        f=F;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(this.times-- > 0){
            f.add(times);
            System.out.println("Produced food '"+times+"'");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class consumer implements Runnable{

    int times;
    food f;

    void consume(food F){
        times=F.times;
        f=F;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(this.times-- > 0){
            f.get();
            System.out.println("Eaten food '"+times+"'");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Produced food '20'
Consumed food '20'
Produced food '19'
Consumed food '19'
.........
```

Comment: Get to the specific issue please. Also, what have you tried in terms of debugging? No one here appreciates being *thrown* a bunch of code...

Comment: I suspect your code works fine -- one food is produced and then one food is consumed in lockstep. However, when you write out the message informing the user of this, you write it out outside the synchronized method, so the messages are jumbled even though the eating is not.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks, now it works fine. I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code works fine -- one food is produced and then one food is consumed in lockstep.

However, when you write out the message informing the user of this, you write it out outside the synchronized method, so the messages are jumbled even though the eating is not.

If you move the printing to the synchronized method, or you synchronize both the call and the printing, it should print in lockstep as well.